# Why did this happen?

Tags: astrophotography

I was filming Venus, and [this](https://gfycat.com/excellentglisteningbasil) was happening from time to time.

Any explanation?

Comment: *Any explanation?* **NO**  You are going to have to **invest some time and effort** in explaining what  you were doing AND how you were doing it. Because **we do not know unless you tell us**. *"I was filming Venus"* is not enough ! filming questions belong on the video stack.

Comment: Please give more details. Were you using autofocus? With a phone, a camcorder, o what camera? Were you using a telescope?
I suspect you were using autofocus. And what you see is the camera trying to focus Venus. But you gave too little information to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

A correctly focused and exposed image of Venus will reveal a nice clean uniform disk. However, since Venus appears to go through phases like our moon, the shape can be a crescent, first quarter, last quater, or full. In any event, unless the camera lens is a super telephoto, the resuting image will be quite small. As your were making this video, the camera was attempting to finalize the focus. As it hunted for focus, it recorded images in various stages of focus. An out-of-focus iamge of a disk (or nearly a disk object) images as a large bright circe. It is normal for an out-of-focus image of a star (planet) to show what is called a difracttion circle. This image has a central core surrounded by a series of rings. In most cases, this image is further distored by residual lens abberations, plus the image undulates due to fact that the light from a astronomical object must traverse severl hunderd miles of earth's atmosphere. The light rays encounter atmospheric turblance which alters thier path moment to moment.

Comment: This is a very good answer to a very bad question.  The question itself ought to be closed and/or needs to be edited to bring it within site standards, and Stack Exchange sites discourage answering bad questions.

Comment: @ Zeiss Ikon -- Bad question?  Question asked was in sincere hope to get to the bottom of this phenomenon. I think this question begged for an answer. Why throw cold water on a learning opportunity?

Comment: @marcus just repeating what I've had hammered into me over 10-12 Stacks.  A sincere, well-intentioned question I'll give you -- but it's very poorly asked, with no details.  It depends on a video that's in a link that might rot and make the question unintelligible.  It's a question that begged to be closed.  TL;DR a bad question is one that's very likely to be closed, not necessarily one without a good reason behind it.  It needs to be edited into site standards.